# How To Rewrite/Redirect url with . in path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a site, which was built by asp.net 2 by another guy long time ago. For some reasons, google indexed lots of pages whose url has . in the path (not the domain part). i.e.

```
http://example.com/CA/Orange/Industrial-Warehouse-Space/1411-N.-St./1234567
```

In the code, UrlRewritingNet is used for rewriting url. One of the rule is:

```
<add name="Rewrite_5"  virtualUrl="^~/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/*$"
       rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
       destinationUrl="~/Location.aspx?id=$5"
       redirectMode = "Permanent"
       ignoreCase="true" />
```

If the url is:

```
http://example.com/CA/Orange/Industrial-Warehouse-Space/1411-N.-St/1234567
```

Note that, no '.' after 'St'. Then the url will be rewritten successfully. But if used

```
http://example.com/CA/Orange/Industrial-Warehouse-Space/1411-N.-St./1234567
```

The site always shows:

```
Server Error in '/' Application
The resource cannot be found.
```

I'm wondering whether there is a way to rewrite/redirect this url to the correct url, or even homepage? Currently, it is on asp.net 2, if needed, can change to other framework too. Any suggestions?

Thanks

- I'm using UrlRewritingNet for rewrite, not sure what the actual url it is trying to rewrite when the error happens. However, I can not capture this in the customError page for 404 (it is a 404 when look at the traffic).

Comment: This regex seems fine to me, and it actually captures '.' in '1411-N.-St.' part. Can you check, to what URL server redirects when accessing those URl with '.'?

Comment: I added more info at the end of post. thanks.

Comment: The simpliest way it to hit not working URL in browser devtools (possibly you need to set it to preserve the log) or from Fiddler. When you will send request, server should response with 301 permanent redirect, and provide redirect URL.